# Why does rsyslog replace tabs with #011?

Tags: nginx, syslog, rsyslog

I am using rsyslog to collect nginx logs. All looks good except the replacing usual tabs with '#011' text.

Example of corrupted output:

```
217.118.93.88#0111473674833.412#0114418687#011...
```

How it should look:

```
217.118.93.88    1473674833.412    4418687    ...
```

Why it is happens and how to disable such replacing?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is intended as a programming Q&A. For questions like this about server configuration, you might want to head over to http://SuperUser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks for pointing!

Answer (score 4):

Try this (which was an undocumented option as far as I could see and found it by skimming through source code):

```
global(
  parser.escapecontrolcharactertab="off"
)
```

There is an issue for this on https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/552.

Comment: Any idea how I can add this to a Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2):

The "quick dirty" fix is to disable escaping special characters.

Add in rsyslog.conf

```
$EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive off
```

Despite it is acceptable solution for my case it could be harmful for more complex situations.